# Amazon Web Scraping Avoid Bot Check

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've seen multiple simple solutions to web scraping data from Amazon periodically to track prices, but every single time I try to run this, it fails thinking that I am a bot. I am trying to pull daily prices for 20-30 products - nothing crazy.

How would I avoid this issue?

Issue - soup returns the following:

```
        To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com.
        For information about migrating to our APIs refer to our Marketplace APIs at https://developer.amazonservices.com/ref=rm_c_sv, or our Product Advertising API at https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html/ref=rm_c_ac for advertising use cases.

<i class="a-icon a-icon-alert"></i>
<h4>Enter the characters you see below</h4>
<p class="a-last">Sorry, we just need to make sure you're not a robot. For best results, please make sure your browser is accepting cookies.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
 
# Function to extract Product Title
def get_title(soup):
     
    try:
        # Outer Tag Object
        title = soup.find("span", attrs={"id":'productTitle'})
 
        # Inner NavigableString Object
        title_value = title.string
 
        # Title as a string value
        title_string = title_value.strip()
 
        # # Printing types of values for efficient understanding
        # print(type(title))
        # print(type(title_value))
        # print(type(title_string))
        # print()
 
    except AttributeError:
        title_string = ""   
 
    return title_string
 
# Function to extract Product Price
def get_price(soup):
 
    try:
        price = soup.find("span", attrs={'id':'priceblock_ourprice'}).string.strip()
 
    except AttributeError:
        price = ""  
 
    return price
 
# Function to extract Product Rating
def get_rating(soup):
 
    try:
        rating = soup.find("i", attrs={'class':'a-icon a-icon-star a-star-4-5'}).string.strip()
         
    except AttributeError:
         
        try:
            rating = soup.find("span", attrs={'class':'a-icon-alt'}).string.strip()
        except:
            rating = "" 
 
    return rating
 
# Function to extract Number of User Reviews
def get_review_count(soup):
    try:
        review_count = soup.find("span", attrs={'id':'acrCustomerReviewText'}).string.strip()
         
    except AttributeError:
        review_count = ""   
 
    return review_count
 
# Function to extract Availability Status
def get_availability(soup):
    try:
        available = soup.find("div", attrs={'id':'availability'})
        available = available.find("span").string.strip()
 
    except AttributeError:
        available = ""  
 
    return available    
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    # Headers for request
    HEADERS = ({'User-Agent':
                'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})
 
    # The webpage URL
    URL = "https://www.amazon.com/DualSense-Wireless-Controller-PlayStation-5/dp/B08FC6C75Y/ref=sr_1_1?crid=1DEVL2M1TZ57Y&dchild=1&keywords=play+station.+5&qid=1608480938&sprefix=play+stat%2Caps%2C256&sr=8-1"
 
    # HTTP Request
    webpage = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
 
    # Soup Object containing all data
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "lxml")
 
    # Function calls to display all necessary product information
    print("Product Title =", get_title(soup))
    print("Product Price =", get_price(soup))
    print("Product Rating =", get_rating(soup))
    print("Number of Product Reviews =", get_review_count(soup))
    print("Availability =", get_availability(soup))
    print()
    print()

exit()
```

Comment: To track amazon prices you can use websites like camelcamelcamel.com. Bypassing a company's security measures is probably off-topic for this site.

Comment: Do they block even your first request or does it happen after a couple of requests? If it is already your first requests you might be able to adjust your header or use `requests.session` and let amazon set some cookies.

Comment: @Gregor - this happens the first time I try any product. Do you have any more details or any resources I can look into for the requests.session or adjusting my header correctly?

Comment: What I usually do is (1) open an incognito tab in Firefox/Chrome, (2) open the network tab [CTRL+SHIFT+C and then network] and (3) call the url I want to inspect. You should see the different requests made by the browser: images, scripts and also the actual url you requested. This should be one of the topmost GET requests, probably with 200 or 30x status code. You can also filter to only show html/document content type. (4) Right click the requests -> copy -> cURL (Windows) or cURL (bash). (5) open Postman and import the copied text as Raw. (6) Use the code generated by Postman as a starter.

Comment: I saw this article suggesting using scraperapi in dealing with IP blocking and dog page responses. This is free for 1000 requests per month which I think is enough for your needs since you mentioned you only want to make requests for 20+ product ASINs. No need to setup a complicated layers of IP rotation, user-agent and captcha resolver. Just use scraperapi, send the URL and it will return clean HTML data for you. I've been using this tool since I discovered it. I can't recommend this enough. 

https://medium.com/@scraperguy/this-could-be-the-answer-to-your-web-scraping-problems-66c88e775c42

Answer (score -2):

Using proxies would solve such problems. Or if there is a captcha like in the response from amazon above you could use captcha solving services.

https://github.com/AdminAnticaptcha/anticaptcha-python for example (but for both proxies and captcha solving you have to pay the most time)